# A query on GCD of polynomials.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I was figuring out the GCD of $p(x)=x^5 + x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + 2x + 1$ and $q(x)=x^5 + x^4 + x^3 -x^2 -x -1$ and it turns out to be $g(x)=x^2+x+1$. But when I substitute $x=1$ in the above polynomials then $p(1)=9$ and $q(1)=0$, so, gcd is $9$ but it doesn't match with $g(1)$ which turns out to be $3$. So, I'm left with wondering where I went wrong.

Comment: Nothing wrong. $3$ divides $9$, and $3$ divides $0$.The gcd of the polynomials is not the same as the individual gcds formed in every individual substitution of $x$!It will only divide all those gcds and be equal to some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gcd calculation of the polynomials is correct. However, this doesn't mean that you can substitute $x$ by any number and the gcd relation will always hold.

For an easy example, $\gcd(x,x+2)=1$, but when $x=2$, $\gcd(2,4)=2$.

Comment: Can we set a lower bound on the actual/(special case) gcd from the algebraic gcd?

Comment: I don't think so. Using a similar example we have $\gcd(x,x+n)=1$ for any $n$, but with $x=n$ it becomes $\gcd(n,2n)=n$, which is arbitrarily large.